# Sorting existing users in the database by multiple columns

Tags: perl, mojolicious, dbix-class

I used the sort function

```
sub sort_users {
  my $self = shift;
  return $self->search(undef, { order_by => [{ -desc => 'data_begin' },
    { -asc => 'username' }]});
}
```

to filter users according to the start date, and in case of equality to be sorted by username, the database looks as follows:

```
user1 2019-09-26 00:00:00
user2 2019-09-26 00:00:00
user3 2019-09-26 00:00:00
user4 2019-09-26 00:00:00
```

following sortings sometimes users are displayed in the following mode

```
user2, user3, user1, user4
```

other times

```
user1, user2, user3, user4.
```

---

**EDIT**

I ran with `DBIC_TRACE = 1` and I got:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM user_access_rights me WHERE ( ( access_rights_id = ? AND date_end >= ? ) ): 'level1', '2019-10-28 07:43:30+0000'
SELECT access_rights_recipient.username, access_rights_recipient.last_login, me.access_rights_id FROM user_access_rights me  JOIN users access_rights_recipient ON access_rights_recipient.username = me.username WHERE ( ( access_rights_id = ? AND date_end >= ? ) ) ORDER BY date_begin DESC, username ASC LIMIT ?: 'level1', '2019-10-28 07:43:30+0000', '2'

INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) RETURNING id: 'level1', '2019-10-28T07:43:29', '2019-10-29T07:43:29', 'user1'
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) RETURNING id: 'level1', '2019-10-28T07:43:29', '2019-10-29T07:43:29', 'user2'
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) RETURNING id: 'level1', '2019-10-28T07:43:29', '2019-10-29T07:43:29', 'user3'
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) RETURNING id: 'level1', '2019-10-28T07:43:29', '2019-10-29T07:43:29', 'user4'
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) RETURNING id: 'level1', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user5'
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) RETURNING id: 'level2', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user6'
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) RETURNING id: 'level2', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user7'
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) RETURNING id: 'level2', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user8'
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) RETURNING id: 'level2', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user9'
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) RETURNING id: 'level2', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user10'
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) RETURNING id: 'level2', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user11'
```

Requires user1 and user2 to be displayed, instead are displayed user5 and user1

Comment: Please show us the code which outputs the ordered usernames as there is no problem with your function.

Comment: This should work... Can you [enable SQL tracing](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Troubleshooting.pod#Tracing-SQL) by setting environment variable `DBIC_TRACE` (`export DBIC_TRACE=1`)? Then you can check the text of the SQL queries in your console or logs. Is the `order by` clause always the same?

Comment: Thanks for the trace. You can see that the `order by` clause in the query matches your code: `ORDER BY date_begin DESC, username ASC`. Did you get the results with the correct ordering in your code that time?

Comment: Sometimes I get the right answer sometimes I don't, is flaky.It must to display user1 and user2, but were displayed user5 and user1.Also I saw that order by work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because user5 is added a second later in the database compared to users who have level 1 and because of this they were displayed in that order, because they are sorted descending with order by function by data_begin.